# Need to convert String to Float variable using Camel-Bindy Format

Tags: apache-camel, bindy

A test file with delimited Data and one of the field is amount and it arrives as a string. To be converted to float. As per camel-bindy i tried a way, but ended with same value without precesions.
Input : 12345678

@DataField(name="AMT", trim=true, pos = 15 , precision=2)
private BigDecimal amount;

Route:
.unmarshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv, Test.class)

O/P:
12345678.00

Its not getting converted to **123456.78**

Please help me with any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotation @DataField provides another method implementation which supports this kind of feature,

@DataField(name="AMT", trim=true, pos = 15 , precision=2, impliedDecimalSeparator = true) 
private BigDecimal amount;

impliedDecimalSeparator decides the decimal position for incoming string field and converts as required.